# git: get working directory staged and non staged back after committing to new branch

Tags: git

While on a `branch b1` with staged and unstaged files, I created a new branch (`backup-changes`) and **committed** those.

```
// Create the backup branch from the branch you are on
$ git checkout -b backup-changes

// make sure it is created and you are on the backup branch
$ git branch -a

// check status and add and commit to the backup branch just created 
$ git status
$ git add .
$ git commit

// do a dry run to see things what are things going to be
$ git push -u origin backup-changes --dry-run

// push to remote
$ git push -u origin backup-changes
```

I did not want to stash it since I wanted a backup on a remote server.

Now, I switch back to the `branch b1`, and want to get back all the staged and unstaged files as they were before I switched to "`backup-changes`" and committed? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand the usefulness of a *backup* in the Git universe. But there are two possible ways:

First possibility is [`git cherry-pick <commit-id>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) in the destination branch (`branch b1`). *Do this only if you understand the behavior of cherry-pick!*

---

The seconde way is to `git reset` the *last commit* in the branch `backup-changes` with:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

And then save the reseted files with `git stash`:

```
git stash save "get back all the staged and unstaged files"
```

Now you can change the branch back:

```
git checkout b1
```

And then make the *stashed* files effective:

```
git stash pop
```

This will removes the *stash*, if you want to keep the stash in the *stash*-list, do only `git stash apply` and the stash is farther saved and showed as `git stash list`. For more information, see the [`git stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: The reason for backup is that at this time am not ready to checkin to remote but want to preserve against data loss in local machine. I believe stash is local, so not stashing as well.